# Determine the target of an SSH connection at runtime

Tags: ssh

I want to determine the target address of an SSH connection with a function call that generate the address to connect to. All of the examples using `ProxyCommand` that I can find online use the `-W` flag to hop to a second machine. I tried that with `localhost` for the second machine, and that worked but required SSH authentication twice which I didn't like.

I am trying to call `ssh` inside of the `ProxyCommand` without forwarding to second hop. Right now, I have in my `.ssh/config` file:

```
Host test
    ProxyCommand ssh user@address
```

When I do `ssh test`, it seems to connect okay but after connecting there is a blank prompt that does not respond to input, so it seems stdin/stdout must not be directed properly.

**Related questions:**

[Use a dynamically obtained hostname with an ssh config entry](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196237/use-a-dynamically-obtained-hostname-with-an-ssh-config-entry)

[How to get HostName from executable script in SSH config file?](https://superuser.com/questions/338303/how-to-get-hostname-from-executable-script-in-ssh-config-file)

[Dynamically generate SSH Host entries in ~/.ssh/config](https://serverfault.com/questions/26422/dynamically-generate-ssh-host-entries-in-ssh-config)

Comment: See  `man ssh_config`

Comment: The point of `-W` is to forward the existing connection instead of opening a new one.  You were asked to authenticate twice precisely because you didn't use `-W`.  Anyway, it isn't clear what you want to do and how that differs from using `-W`.

Comment: No, I was asked to authenticate twice when I **did** use `-W`. I want `ssh test` to connect as though as I had entered `ssh user@address` when I have the given block in `.ssh/config`. (And I can't just put `address` in the `HostName` entry because I want to replace it with `$(generate_address)` that will generate the address dynamically when ssh is called.

Comment: Use `ssh-agent` then.

Comment: If you want to go from machine A to B to C, you need to add the address of machine B to `HostName`, and the address of machine C to the `ssh` command in the `ProxyCommand` line.

Comment: I'm only trying to go from A to B. I only mentioned `-W` because every example I could find online uses it. I don't think I need it here but I can't see how to use `ProxyCommand` without it. It seems like using the `-W localhost` method should work if I use `ssh-agent` but how do I call `ssh-agent` within `ProxyCommand` and make sure the environment variables get to the ssh call? I don't want to leave `ssh-agent` running all the time, so I want to use it with a short lifetime inside `ProxyCommand`.

Comment: Run `ssh-agent bash`.  This will run a new shell; exit the shell when you want to kill the agent.  Run `ssh-add` in the agent shell to add your keys.  Back to your post: I still have no idea what you're trying to achieve.  Why do you need to run a _second_ ssh if you only need to go from A to B.

Comment: I want `ssh` to treat `test` as though it were `address` where `address` is generated dynamically by another script that is called when `ssh` is called (rather than reading the `HostName` entry in `.ssh/config` for `Host test`). I could get this functionality by writing a function that does the substitution and then calls ssh. However, I would like `ssh` to do the substitution because I use other programs (e.g. `vncviewer`, `attic`) that call `ssh` internally, so I have to write substituion functions for each. Perhaps I misunderstood `ProxyCommand` and it's not possible to use it this way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you don't pass a command to `ssh`, it runs a shell, which expects commands on its standard input. But you aren't passing it shell commands, you're passing it SSH traffic. Hilarity ensues.

Tunnelling is the whole point of `ProxyCommand`. This example tunnels an SSH connection inside an SSH connection. If you don't want to tunnel, `ProxyCommand` is not what you're looking for.

Since OpenSSH 6.4, you can use a `Match` directive with the `exec` keyword to include blocks conditionally based on a run-time directive. A typical use case is to have different actual host names or proxy commands depending on where your laptop is. Each `Match` block replaces a `Host` block, and you can't use the output of the command to determine the host name, only the fact that it exited with status 0.

```
# Connection inside ACME network
Match host foo exec on-acme-network
HostName foo.acme.local

# Connection from outside ACME
Host foo
HostName foo.example.com
```

Proxying is another option. To make a connection to a host name and port that are determined at connection time, you can use [netcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) to set up the TCP connection.

```
Host foo
ProxyCommand nc $(determine-target-host-name) 22
```

If you want a fully dynamic `.ssh/config`, you can make it a named pipe and ensure that a process is always writing to it. Or put it on [scriptfs](https://code.google.com/p/scriptfs/).

Comment: I'd rather call that the *old* way of doing it. Prior to the `ssh` client supporting the `-W` switch, it was the normal way of doing things, but I think it makes sense to mention the `ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p user@address` form for cases where `ssh -W` **is** available. Personally I prefer the latter method always, because not on all jump hosts will I have `nc` or the rights to install it, but `ssh` is often recent enough.

Comment: @0xC0000022L Yes, good point, thanks. I tend to forget about this newfangled 21st century stuff...

Comment: Isn't your suggestion just the standard way to do a two-hop ssh connection? I want to do just one hop but I want that hop to be to an address that is looked up at run time (see comments under the question). I added links to some other questions I found asking basically the same thing. From those, it seems like this is not possible without writing a wrapper around ssh (doesn't work well with programs that call ssh) or using local DNS (hard since I don't have root access on the server where I want to ssh from), unless `-W` is passed localhost but it requires entering a password twice.

Comment: @ws_e_c421 Ah, ok. Your question was [confusing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) because the whole point of `ProxyCommand` is to do a two-hop connection. I've changed my answer to address your actual question.

Comment: @Gilles: are you suggesting to pass the `ProxyCommand` stanza with the command substitution on the command line (`-o`) or is it actually possible to put this into the `~/.ssh/config` file? I'm asking because Paramiko for one doesn't handle this syntax in its OpenSSH config parsing.

Comment: @0xC0000022L I'm not sure what you're suggesting but the `ProxyCommand` line stays within the `.ssh/config` file, it's not part of any command substitution, and it can't be the output of a command. This does require a rather recent OpenSSH client. I'm not surprised that Paramiko wouldn't have this feature; you can of course trivially do the same in Python, but parsing the OpenSSH configuration file would be significant work.

Comment: @Gilles: Paramiko already does parsing. In fact it is often used for the task in absence of any alternatives. Interesting that new OpenSSH clients have this feature. I was really just asking, because I didn't know of that feature. Thanks.

Comment: In case it's helpful to anyone else: I could not get `ssh-agent` to work fully inside of `ProxyCommand`. I was able to use `ssh-agent` as the `ProxyCommand` and have it call a script that executed `ssh-add` and `ssh -W` but I couldn't get it to forward the agent to the `localhost` connection (even with agent forwarding enabled for `ssh` and `sshd` on both sides). My workaround was to create a key without a passphrase and set `from="127.0.0.1"` in `authorized_keys`, set this key is with `IdentityFile` in `ssh_config` and set the key with passphrase with `-i` in the `ssh -W` command.

Comment: Just to clarify -- using `ssh-agent` the way I described didn't work in the sense that I was still asked for a passphrase twice. The ssh connection itself worked after supplying the passphrase twice. Running the agent beforehand would probably work, but I didn't want to leave an agent running, so I wanted something that would always ask for a passphrase when a connection was made (but only ask once).

Comment: @Gilles Shouldn't your `ProxyCommand` be `ssh -W localhost:%p "$(real-foo-name-port)"`?

Comment: @ws_e_c421 Ah, I see. Having ssh-agent running permanently is the normal way to use it. You could run `ssh-agent ssh originaltarget` but that would defeat the purpose of automating the target lookup. A dynamic `.ssh/config` would be your best bet then.

Comment: @ws_e_c421 Sorry, I was being silly. There's no need to tunnel SSH inside SSH here. You need to establish a TCP connection to a dynamically-determined target address, and that's the job of `ProxyCommand` — so call netcat and make it do that. See my edit.

Comment: `nc` works perfectly. For some reason, I thought `ssh` had to make its own connections, but now I see that that is not the case.